# Celery task always PENDING

Tags: python, windows, redis, celery

I try to run Celery example on Windows with redis backend. The code looks like:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('risktools.distributed.celery_tasks',
             backend='redis://localhost',
             broker='redis://localhost')

@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def add_2(x, y):
    return x + y
```

I start the tasks using iPython console:

```
>>> result_1 = add.delay(1, 2)    
>>> result_1.state
'PENDING'
>>> result_2 = add_2.delay(2, 3)    
>>> result_2.state
'PENDING'
```

It seems that both tasks were not executed, but Celery worker output shows that they succeeded:

```
[2014-12-08 15:00:09,262: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: risktools.distributed.celery_tasks.add[01dedca1-2db2-48df-a4d6-2f06fe285e45]
[2014-12-08 15:00:09,267: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery_tasks.add[01dedca1-2db2-48df-a4d6-2f06fe28
5e45] succeeded in 0.0019998550415s: 3
[2014-12-08 15:00:24,219: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: risktools.distributed.celery_tasks.add[cb5505ce-cf93-4f5e-aebb-9b2d98a11320]
[2014-12-08 15:00:24,230: INFO/MainProcess] Task celery_tasks.add[cb5505ce-cf93-4f5e-aebb-9b2d98a1
1320] succeeded in 0.010999917984s: 5
```

I've tried to troubleshoot this issue according to [Celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#result-backend-does-not-work-or-tasks-are-always-in-pending-state), but none of the advices were useful. What am I doing wrong and how can I receive results from a Celery task?

**UPD:**
I've added a task without `ignore_result` parameter, but nothing has changed

```
@app.task
def add_3(x, y):
    return x + y

>>>r = add_3.delay(2, 2)
>>>r.state
'PENDING'
```

Comment: `.get()` will return the result.  Not sure why you are always getting `PENDING` tho

Comment: @user2097159 `.get()` fails with `TimeoutError: The operation timed out.`

Comment: Did you set the `BROKER_URL` anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery 'Getting Started' not able to retrieve results; always pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495613/celery-getting-started-not-able-to-retrieve-results-always-pending)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [Celery 'Getting Started' not able to retrieve results; always pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495613/celery-getting-started-not-able-to-retrieve-results-always-pending) and https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2146 it is a Windows issue.

Celery `-P threads` or `--pool=solo` options solves the issue.

Comment: Mac also encounters this issue as well, thanks for the tips

Comment: Life Save for windows , thanks man

Answer (score 7):

Instead of `Celery --pool=solo` option, try `-P threads` on Windows.

Comment: This sounds like a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 5):

Setting `CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True` (or track_started=True on individual tasks) can also help - this will enable the STARTED status.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `ignore_result=False` from the celery docs

```
Task.ignore_result

Don’t store task state. Note that this means you can’t 
use AsyncResult to check if the task is ready, or get its return value.
```

Comment: I still get `PENDING` state (see `add_3` method in UPD)

Comment: this worked for me nicely, thanks! (note that CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED was already set to `True`)

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone.

my celery config:

```
-------------- celery@DESKTOP-FD38GOO v4.4.2 (cliffs)
--- ***** -----
-- ******* ---- Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 2020-04-17 06:58:18
- *** --- * ---
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         mysite:0x25cfd40d208
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/1
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (thread)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . mysite.celery.debug_task
  . supplier.tasks.add
  . supplier.tasks.count_widgets
  . supplier.tasks.count_widgets2
  . supplier.tasks.mul
  . supplier.tasks.xsum
```

i have fixed such issue:

i pending such issue about 1 days, and try uninstall redis and install redis on windows 10 some times.

at last i found there are not concurrency config.

first solution:

> celery -A mysite worker -l info -P threads

second solution:

> celery -A mysite worker -l info --pool=solo

my celery config:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERYD_LOG_FILE = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR, 'celery', 'logs')   
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Other way to do it if you are setting the configuration from Celery object -

```
app = Celery("MyTasks")
app.conf.task_track_started = True
app.conf.task_ignore_result = False
..
..
```