# Kombu/Celery messaging

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, kombu

I have a simple application that sends & receives messages, kombu, and uses Celery to task the message. Kombu alon, I can receive the message properly. when I send "Hello", kombu receives "Hello". But when I added the task, what kombu receives is the task ID of the celery.

My purpose for this project is so that I can schedule when to send and receive messages, hence Celery.

What I would like to know is why is kombu receiving the task id instead of the sent message? I have searched and searched and have not found any related results on this matter. I am a beginner in using this applications and I would appreciate some help in fixing this matter.

My codes:

task.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://xx:xx@localhost/xx', backend='amqp://')

@app.task(name='task.add')
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

send.py

```
import kombu
from task import add
#declare connection with broker connection
connection = kombu.Connection(hostname='xx',
                              userid='xx',
                              password='xx',
                              virtual_host='xx')

connection.connect()
if connection.connect() is False:
    print("not connected")
else:
    print("connected")

#checks if connection is okay


#rabbitmq connection
channel = connection.channel()

#queue & exchange for kombu
exchange = kombu.Exchange('exchnge', type='direct')
queue = kombu.Queue('kombu_queue', exchange, routing_key='queue1')

#message here

x = input ("Enter first name: ")
y = input ("Enter last name: ")
result= add.delay(x,y)
print(result)



#syntax used for sending messages to queue
producer = kombu.Producer(channel, exchange)
producer.publish(result,
                 exchange = exchange,
                 routing_key='queue1')

print("Message sent: [x]")
connection.release()
```

receive.py

```
import kombu

#receive
connection = kombu.Connection(hostname='xx',
                              userid='xx',
                              password='xx',
                              virtual_host='xx')
connection.connect()

channel = connection.channel()

exchange = kombu.Exchange('exchnge', type='direct')
queue = kombu.Queue('kombu_queue', exchange, routing_key='queue1')

print("Waiting for messages...")
def callback(body, message):
    print('Got message - %s' % body)
    message.ack()

consumer = kombu.Consumer(channel,
                          queues=queue,
                          callbacks=[callback])
consumer.consume()

while True:
    connection.drain_events()
```

I am using:

```
Kombu 3.0.26
Celery 3.1.18
RabbitMQ as the broker
```

What I sent:

```
xxx
yyy
```

What kombu receives:

```
Got message - d22880c9-b22c-48d8-bc96-5d839b224f2a
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Celery 'Getting Started' not able to retrieve results; always pending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495613/celery-getting-started-not-able-to-retrieve-results-always-pending)

Comment: This question is closed already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I found an answer to my problem and to anyone who may come across this kind of problem, I'll share the answer that worked for me.**

[I found the solution here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506186/4652234)

[Or here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/897) - user **jennaliu** answer may probably help you if the first link didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `result.get()` to receive the actual value of `add.delay()`. What you are seeing as the message body is [`AsyncResult`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html#celery.result.AsyncResult) instance in string format. Which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It says `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` when I added result.get() after result = add.delay(x,y)